# TikZ: Using imported data to customize node and path styles

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, datatool

I would like to automatically adapt the features of a flow diagram depending on my data. Here the example is for line widths, but I would like to use the same principle also for node sizes.

I have saved this data as a text file, with a column containing the name of the data point, a second column corresponding to the actual text I would like to be displayed, and a third column with the parameter I would like to use in a file called `flows.txt`:

```
Z2A, 2$\pm$0, 0.5
A2B, 110$\pm$6, 2.5
```

I have successfully imported the data with the package `datatool`, and I am able to have it written as text on my diagram with the custom-defined command `\flowvar` that fetches the required data, but I don't manage to use it to modify graphical parameters.

```
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={thekey,thevalue,thewidth}]{myflows}{flow.txt}
\newcommand{\flowvar}[1]{\DTLfetch{myflows}{thekey}{#1}{thevalue}}
\newcommand{\flowwidth}[1]{\DTLfetch{myflows}{thekey}{#1}{thewidth}}
```

So the following command works:

```
\path [ARROW] ([shift={(-1.5,0)}]a.west) -- (a.west) node[pos=0.5,above] {\scriptsize \flowvar{Z2A}};
```

But if I try to adapt the line width as follows, it gives an error:

```
\path [ARROW, line width = \flowwidth{Z2A} mm] ([shift={(-1.5,0)}]a.west) -- (a.west) node[pos=0.5,above] {\scriptsize \flowvar{Z2A}};
```

I have tried changing the string so that it contains the unit or not (`0.5` vs. `0.5 mm`), to no avail. I have also tried to define a new variable with tikzset and use it (as was suggested in another question): `\tikzset{\flowwidth{A2B}/.store in=\tempwidth}`

Here is a sample of my code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\DTLsetseparator{, }
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{flow.txt}
Z2A, 2$\pm$0, 0.5
A2B, 110$\pm$6, 2.5
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

% For importing data
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={thekey,thevalue,thewidth}]{myflows}{flow.txt}
\newcommand{\flowvar}[1]{\DTLfetch{myflows}{thekey}{#1}{thevalue}}
\newcommand{\flowwidth}[1]{\DTLfetch{myflows}{thekey}{#1}{thewidth}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[BOX/.style={rectangle, draw, text centered},
        ARROW/.style      ={draw,-latex', line width = 0.5mm}]

% BOXES
\node [BOX] (a) {A};    
\node [BOX, below= of a]  (b) {B};

% ARROWS
\path [ARROW] ([shift={(-1.5,0)}]a.west) -- (a.west) node[pos=0.5,above] {\scriptsize \flowvar{Z2A}};
\path [ARROW, line width = 2 mm] (a.south) -- (b.north) node[pos=0.5,left] {\scriptsize \flowvar{A2B}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And what the result looks like:

[image: Preview of the resulting diagram]

I suspect the problem is that I don't know how to handle variables in LaTeX/TikZ. Would someone have any suggestions on how to use imported data as graphical parameters?

Thank you very much for reading!

Comment: Welcome.  For those not `tikz` savvy, how would you accomplish what you want, using explicit inputs, rather than `\flowwidth{}`?  And does it work that way, for starters?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have changed an arrow so that it has a modified line width and added a picture of my result. Or did you mean something different?

Comment: That helps.  You want to be able to change the `line width=` parameter based on file input.

Comment: Yes exactly, and this input is saved in an external text file. I will precise it in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than `datatool`, I use `readarray` to get the file data into a `\def` and then employ `listofitems` (loaded by `readarray`) to digest the `\def` and make appropriate assignments.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{flow.txt}
Z2A, 2$\pm$0, 0.5 mm
A2B, 110$\pm$6, 2.0 mm
\end{filecontents*}
% USE readarray  TO GET THE DATA INTO A \def
\usepackage{readarray}
\readarraysepchar{;}
\readdef{flow.txt}\myflowdef
% USE listofitems TO DIGEST THE \def APPROPRIATELY
\setsepchar{;/,}
\ignoreemptyitems
\readlist*\myflowdata{\myflowdef}
\foreachitem\i\in\myflowdata[]{%
  \expandafter\edef\csname\myflowdata[\icnt,1]var\endcsname{\myflowdata[\icnt,2]}%
  \expandafter\edef\csname\myflowdata[\icnt,1]width\endcsname{\myflowdata[\icnt,3]}%
}
% For importing data
\newcommand{\flowvar}[1]{\csname#1var\endcsname}
\newcommand{\flowwidth}[1]{\csname#1width\endcsname}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[BOX/.style={rectangle, draw, text centered},
        ARROW/.style      ={draw,-latex', line width = 0.5mm}]
% BOXES
\node [BOX] (a) {A};    
\node [BOX, below= of a]  (b) {B};

% ARROWS
\path [ARROW, line width=\flowwidth{Z2A}] ([shift={(-1.5,0)}]a.west) -- (a.west) node[pos=0.5,above] {\scriptsize \flowvar{Z2A}};
\path [ARROW, line width=\flowwidth{A2B}] (a.south) -- (b.north) node[pos=0.5,left] {\scriptsize \flowvar{A2B}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's been a while now, but I realize that I didn't entirely grasp the subtleties of your answer. I've been trying to build upon it, but encounter some problems. If you would have time to have a look at this new question, I would be immensely grateful:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397145/using-a-conditional-on-a-custom-defined-variable